# No quasi-isomorphism

Tags: category-theory, modules, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, functors

I am trying to prove the following:

Let $R=\mathbb{C}[t]/(t^2)$ and $ N=R/(t)=\mathbb{C}[t]/(t)$, define $f:R\to R$ by $f(r)=rt$. Then the following two chain complexes have the same cohomology for each $i$

$C=(\dots \to 0 \to R \to^{f} R \to 0 \to \dots), N=(\dots \to 0 \to N \to^{0} N \to 0 \to \dots)$

Show that there is no quasi isomorphism from $C$ to $D$ nor from $D$ to $C$.

Comment: One approach: classify all homomorphisms $R \to N$ and $N \to R$. This allows you classify all chain maps $C \to D$ and $D \to C$. Compute, for each chain map, the induced maps on cohomology, and deduce that none of the maps is a quasi-isomorphism.

Comment: I know how to compute the cohomology of each order. But I'm not sure that I got the idea of computing induced maps on cohomology.

Comment: Will the cohomology map induced by $f$ be the identity?

Comment: The definition of "quasi-isomorphism" is precisely "a chain map whose induced maps on cohomology are all isomorphisms", so it's imperative that you understand what these induced maps are to even understand what the question is asking. For each chain complex $C$, we get cohomology groups/modules/objects $H^i(C)$ for each $i \in \mathbb{Z}$. In fact, $H^i$ is always a functor; in particular, whenever $f : C \to D$ is a chain map, we get induced maps $H^i(f) : H^i(C) \to H^i(D)$. It's a good exercise to try to define these maps for yourself! (let me know if you get stuck)

Comment: Notably, these induced maps I'm talking about come from chain maps (maps between chain complexes), not from the maps that comprise a given chain complex. As such, the $f$ in your setup doesn't induce a map on cohomology (in standard terminology).